# creating Multi-dimentional array and JSON parsing

Tags: javascript, json

i have a fiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/prantikv/eqqd6xfm/3/

i have data as such

```
var info={
"company1":[
   {"employee":"*2"},
   {"rooms":"*6"},
   {"vehicals":"3"},
],

"company2":[
    {"employee":"*2"},
    {"rooms":"*6"},
    {"vehicals":"3"},
],
"company3":[
    {"employee":"*2"},
    {"rooms":"*6"},
    {"vehicals":"3"},
]
```

i get the data from an a json file.
what i want to do is that i want to create individial company variables so that i can load them up quickly without other company data

so what i do is this

```
var companiesArray=[];
for(company in info){
console.log("company--> "+company);//company1,2,etc 
var detailsArray=[];

for(var i=0;i<info[company].length;i++)   
{
 //loop through the inner array which has the detials
    for(var details in info[company][i]){
     var detailsValue=info[company][i][details];
    detailsArray[details]=detailsValue;
   }
 }

 companiesArray[company]=[company,detailsArray];
}
```

console.log(companiesArray);

so when i try to get the data i have to do something like this

```
companiesArray['company1'][1].employee
```

what i want to do is this

```
companiesArray['company1'].employee
```

where am i going wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If You don't want to /cannot change the JSON, simply change

```
detailsArray = []
```

to

```
detailsObject = {}
```

and

```
companiesArray[company]=[company,detailsArray];
```

to

```
companiesArray[company]=detailsObject;
```

Now you can use

```
companiesArray['company1'].employee
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to form your json like this:

```
var info={
  "company1": {
    "employee":"*2",
    "rooms":"*6",
    "vehicals":"3"
  },    
  "company2": {
    "employee":"*2",
    "rooms":"*6",
    "vehicals":"3"
  },
  "company3": {
    "employee":"*2",
    "rooms":"*6",
    "vehicals":"3"
  }
};
```

Use curly braces ({}) instead of brackets ([]) in order to create objects accessible with the dot notation like this: 
`info.company1.employee`

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @Pavel Gatnar and @Guillaume. This is a very bad data structure. If you can't change the structure only then should you use the following code.

```
    var info = {
        "company1": [{
            "employee": "*2"
        }, {
            "rooms": "*6"
        }, {
            "vehicals": "3"
        }],
        "company2": [{
            "employee": "*2"
        }, {
            "rooms": "*6"
        }, {
            "vehicals": "3"
        }],
        "company3": [{
            "employee": "*2"
        }, {
            "rooms": "*6"
        }, {
            "vehicals": "3"
        }]
    };

    var companies = {},
        companyNames = Object.keys(info);

    companyNames.forEach(function (companyName) {
       var companyInfo =  info[companyName],
           company = {};

       companyInfo.forEach(function (properties) {
            var innerPropertyName = Object.keys(properties);

            innerPropertyName.forEach(function (property) {
                company[property] = properties[property];
            });
       });
       companies[companyName] = company;
    });

    console.log(companies);
```

check out the fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/adityasharat/g3jdnoyw/)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var info={
    "company1":[
       {"employee":"*2"},
       {"rooms":"*6"},
       {"vehicals":"3"},
    ],

    "company2":[
        {"employee":"*2"},
        {"rooms":"*6"},
        {"vehicals":"3"},
    ],
    "company3":[
        {"employee":"*2"},
        {"rooms":"*6"},
        {"vehicals":"3"},
    ]
};
var companiesArray = {};
for(company in info){
    var detailsArray = {};
    for(var i=0;i<info[company].length;i++) {
        for(var details in info[company][i]){ 
            var detailsValue=info[company][i][details];
            detailsArray[details]=detailsValue;
        }
     }
     companiesArray[company]=detailsArray;
}
console.log(companiesArray['company1'].employee);
```